# Вывод переменной через текст в PyGame

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

Как вывести переменную на экран в pygame?
Оно выдает ошибку, что мол ожидает строку в юникоде или байтовом виде.

```
score = 0

font = pygame.font.Font(None, 20)

text = font.render("Очки: ", True, red)
text2 = font.render(score, True, red)

win.blit(text, [20,20])
win.blit(text2, [70,20])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У Вас `score` -- это число, а метод `render` в качестве первого аргумента ожидает строку. Для решения данной проблемы нужно конвертировать `score` в строку, например, с помощью метода `str()`:

```
text2 = font.render(str(score), True, red)
```

[Документация](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/font.html#pygame.font.Font.render) на метод `render`.